# SQLite - selecting non-null values from two columns

Tags: android, sqlite

In my SQL table, there is a column for image paths and a column for video paths. I'm in the process of creating a gallery and I want to select all image and video paths from my table that are not null.

I think this is the way to retrieve all non-null values from one column:

`Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, null, COLUMN_1 + " IS NOT NULL", null, null, null, null);`

I would then add all these Strings to an array and return the array. But is there a way to run through the table just once and grab all non-null values from two columns? I'm new to SQL so I'm not sure. I would want to grab all the paths in the order they were added to the table, so the gallery is in chronological order.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a raw query. Something like this:

```
Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase()
               .rawQuery("select image_path, video_path from table_name where image_path is not null or video_path is not null"); 

if (cursor.getCount() > 0) 
{               
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
           cursor.getColumnIndex("image_path");
           cursor.getColumnIndex("video_path");
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    cursor.close();
}
```

I presume all records which have an image or video is what you want!

Comment: Would you be able to expand on that answer or point me to an example? I actually only want the image or video path columns. Each row represents an object, and each object may or may not have an image/video path. I just want the paths and nothing else.